# How do you configure sendmail to reject Email with a Date header too far from real time?

Tags: smtp, email-server, spam, sendmail, spam-filter

A friend of mine using (I believe) `qmail` has it configured to reject, as SPAM, any incoming Email with a Date: header that is too far from real time.  I can't figure out how to do this with sendmail.  How do you do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sendmail is evil ;)
One solution could be to install [SpamAssassin](http://spamassassin.apache.org/) and integrate it with [spamass-milter](http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/spamass-milt/) into your mail services. This has the advantage that you could activate lot of other Anti-Spam rules. Or just write your own plugins which is really easy.

Comment: I already have ClamAV integrated with sendmail with its milter, but I didn't realize that Spam Assassin also had a milter.  I'll look into that.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Sendmail isn't good at filtering messages on its own.

In theory it wouldn't take much to write a simple `milter` (sendmail mail filter) plugin to do just that job.

However if spam prevention is the primary requirement, then why not go the whole hog and plugin a full anti-spam system?

Answer (score 0):

Consider integrating something like MailScanner which can utilize SpamAssassin, ClamAV, and other external tools for detecting spam, viruses, and other nasties.

Also, you probably only want to use a date too far in the future or past as part of a spam score rather than rejecting it outright. You risk catching legitimate senders with misconfigured systems or mail clients in this way.